# tensorflow seems to recognize my gpu but don't use it

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I just followed the tutorial on how to install cuda cudnn etc to use the gpu with tensorflow.
When I run:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

It returns `Num GPUs Available:  1`

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib 
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

returns

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 5352387470003847961
xla_global_id: -1
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 6273040384
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 1135099878766203926
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 Super, pci bus id: 
0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5"
xla_global_id: 416903419
]
```

So I think that my GPU is recognized. However when I launch:

```
m=32
refmodel = tf.keras.Sequential()
refmodel.add(Flatten(input_shape=data_train[0].shape))
refmodel.add(Dense(m, activation='sigmoid'))
refmodel.add(Dense(len(classes)))

refmodel.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
t=time()
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    history1 = refmodel.fit(data_train, target_train, epochs=7, validation_data= 
(data_test, target_test), batch_size=64)
print(time()-t)
```

It seems to take exactly the same time to run as before. Is this normal (with a RTX 2070S) or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: When you say it takes the same time "as before" you mean before installing CUDA and/or setting up the GPU?

Comment: Your model is too simple to benefit from GPU acceleration.

Comment: @user2246849 I mean before both, I didn't see any difference at any point.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy My model is maybe simple but takes a looong time when I put epochs=100 for example and I thought using my gpu would have help